# ng-repeat when some items are parsed from backend into html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to display an arrays and be able to reload it. Some items are provided from backend already in html (as a part of SEO). The rest are from frontend arrays.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello Mary!</p>
  <p ng-repeat="name in names">Hello {{ name }}!</p>
  <button ng-click="loadNew()">Load New</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ['Peter', 'Jack'];

  $scope.loadNew = function() {
    $scope.names = ['Joe', 'Jennifer'];
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ANdV8G9tLahxtaX6vvkK?p=preview

As you can see, the `<p>Hello Mary!</p>` are already there from backend. But its basically the same as items in `ng-repeat` loop.

I want to click **Load New** and reload everything within the `MainCtrl` including the elements from backend.

**How to do that?**

Because right now `ng-repeat` do not have knowledge of elements not within its loop. I was thinking about deleting the DOMs (from backend) manually using jQuery but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you add an attribute to the `<p>Hello Mary!</p>`?

Comment: As you say, deleting from Dom is not the angular way so avoid things like that. Think about the architecture of your Application. You print out an Name from Backend then loop over names in Frontend - is that really necessary?

Comment: @DavinTryon Yes, I can modify backend html. What you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide static content after loading content from server

```
<p ng-if="showStatic">Hello Mary!</p>
```

and

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ['Peter', 'Jack'];
  $scope.showStatic = true;
  $scope.loadNew = function() {
    $scope.names = ['Joe', 'Jennifer'];
    $scope.showStatic = false;
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fuhJSvAGRPl5Jasusref?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

One simple way, would be to add the concept of a refresh, and `ng-if` out all the server-provided values.  This only works if you can add an attribute to the server-provided markup:

Here is an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kxqHHk?p=preview).

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ['Peter', 'Jack'];

  $scope.loadNew = function() {       
    $scope.names = ['Joe', 'Jennifer'];
    $scope.refreshed = true;
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p ng-if="!refreshed">Hello Mary!</p>
  <p ng-repeat="name in names">Hello {{ name }}!</p>
  <button ng-click="loadNew()">Load New</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to select all of the items from the backend and put them into the names array:

In your controller, do:

```
angular.element('[ng-controller=MainCtrl] p:eq(0)').each(function(){
    $scope.push(angular.element(this).text().replace('Hello ', ''));
});
```

That will select "Hello Mary" and remove the "Hello " and put the "Mary" into the names array.

Not sure if this helps, but it does what you asked to do.